# Form dropdown issues on Firefox and IE with PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress, firefox, cross-browser

I have a form set up with a dropdown that populates options via PHP. It works exactly as expected on Chrome, however when doing some cross browser testing the dropdown doesn't seem to be populating with all of the options, just 'Option'. Have no idea what could be causing this as it hasn't happened before. Code and screenshot below:

```
                <div class="input-field select">

                    <select name="groups[]" id="groups" multiple="true">
                        <?php
                        foreach ( $groups as $group ) { ?>
                            <optgroup label="<?php echo $group['name']; ?>">
                                <?php 
                                foreach ( $group['children'] as $id => $name ) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>" <?php 
                                    if ( in_array( $id, $groups ) ) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>
                                        <?php echo $name; ?>
                                    </option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </optgroup>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>

                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working". What is the expected behaviour and what is actually happening?

Comment: As in the screenshot only a selected course appears rather than a full list of options. Will update my question to be clearer

Comment: Please do, because we have no way of knowing whether there was only a single option in your list. Also, please include the HTML that is generated, and CSS that applies to it, co we can understand what is actually happening.

Comment: Done, thanks for the note

Comment: The HTML is included, and the CSS is unnecessary

Comment: No, you have included the PHP, not the generated HTML. And yes the CSS *is* necessary - it is one of the components that controls the display of the dropdown. If we ask for something, its usually for a reason - let *us* decide if something is necessary or not, if you are looking for our help with this.